# How to send params data to the screen which is in drawer stack. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, parameters, navigation

How to send Params data to the screen which is in drawer stack.

here is my code from login screen I want to send loginAs data to the homeScreen which is in MyDrawer stack.

```
 onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("MyDrawer", {loginAs : `${this.state.nature}`})}
```

here is my MyDrawer stack

```
function App({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="loginScreen" component={loginScreen}  options={{headerShown: false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MyDrawer" component={MyDrawer}  options={{headerShown: false}} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

function MyDrawer({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="homeScreen">
      <Drawer.Screen name="homeSreen" component={homeScreenStack} 
       options={{drawerLabel: 'Home',}}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You navigate directly to your `homeScreen` like this

```js
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("homeScreen", {loginAs : `${this.state.nature}`})}
```

And then in your `homeScreenStack` component you get your `params` like you'd noramlly do

```js
    const loginAs = navigation.params?.loginAs;
```

**Note:** you have a typo in the `name` property of your `Drawer.Screen` you typed  `homeSreen` instead of `homeScreen` so be aware of that.